# How to fix ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in my wp-admin at localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, google-chrome

I am trying to put a site on localhost, but I'm having such problems with this. I have changed the url in `myslq` and updated the wp-config and `.htaccess`, this worked and now I can see the layout, but when I try to access `wp-admin` occurs then

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

This is an existing site, but I need to make some changes and I decided to put on localhost. I have tried to change the plugins folder name, change the `.htaccess`, update the database again, but nothing worked.

Comment: This is an error in your server. Its probably not related to msql or wordpress itself. Is the apache server running?

Comment: I don't think so, because I have other sites here and I am not having this problem :s

Comment: It´s Wamp Server

Comment: Post a screenshot of the browser

Comment: [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/ns0xxc)

Comment: you're running it over ssl

Comment: replace https with http in the address bar

Comment: I replaced to http but when the page is loading, the page redirects to https

Comment: There's something in either your .htaccess or wordpress config that's doing that

Comment: [htacces](https://prnt.sc/ns177l) I changed to default .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`iptables -I INPUT -s <allowed_ip> -j ACCEPT`

`ufw allow from <allowed_ip>`